# Erro uploading Excel to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, exceljs

I'm using the 'exceljs' lib. It's work great on my local node server. Now I'm trying to use Firebase Functions to upload the excel file to Google Cloud storage.

This is the entire code I'm using:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

admin.initializeApp();

var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Relatório Consolidado');



function startExcel(){

  worksheet.columns = [
    { header: 'Empresa', key: 'empresa', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Data criação', key: 'data_criacao', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Responsável agendamento', key: 'agendador', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Colaborador', key: 'colaborador', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Endereço', key: 'endereco', width: 25 },
    { header: 'CPF', key: 'cpf', width: 25 },
    { header: 'CTPS', key: 'ctps', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Função', key: 'funcao', width: 25 },

    { header: 'Data agendado', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Data atendimento médico', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Data inicio atendimento', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Data inicio exames', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Tipo de exame', key: 'valor_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Exames realizados', key: 'valor_produto', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Status atendimento', key: 'tipoPagamento', width: 25 },
    { header: 'Status exames', key: 'centroCustoStr', width: 25 }
  ];        
}

function salvaExcel(){

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

      let filename = `/tmp/Relatorio.xlsx`
      let bucketName = 'gs://xxx.appspot.com/Relatorios'
      const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucketName);      

      workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filename)
      .then(() => {

      console.log('Excel criado com sucesso! Enviando upload do arquivo: ' + filename)          

        const metadata = {
          contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        };

        bucket.upload(filename, metadata)

        .then(() => {
          const theFile = bucket.file(filename);
          theFile.getSignedURL(signedUrlOptions)

          .then((signedUrl) => {
            resolve(signedUrl)
          });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject('Erro ao realizar upload: ' + error)
        })                      
      })  

      .catch((error) => {
        reject('Erro ao realizar upload: ' + error)
      })         

  })    
}

startExcel()


/**********************************
 * Relatórios
 ********************************/

function relatorios(change, context){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const snapshot = change.after
    const data = snapshot.val()  

    verificaRelatorioAgendamentos(change)

    .then(() => {
      resolve()

    })

    .catch((error => {                
      reject(error)

    }))

  })           
}


function verificaRelatorioAgendamentos(change, context){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const snapshot = change.after
    const data = snapshot.val()      
    const dataInicial = data.dataInicial    
    const year = moment(dataInicial).format('YYYY')
    const month = moment(dataInicial).format('MM')
    const state = 'DF'    
    let path = "/agendamentos/" + state + "/" +  year + "/" + month

    const relatorios = admin.database().ref(path).once('value');

    return Promise.all([relatorios])

      .then(results => {                

        let valores = results[0]
        criaRelatorioAgendamentos(valores)

        .then(() => {
          resolve()

        })

        .catch((error => {          
          reject(error)

        }))

    })

  })       

}


function criaRelatorioAgendamentos(results){

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let promises = []

    results.forEach(element => {

      let promise = new Promise(function(resolveExcel){ 

        let data = element.val()        

        worksheet.addRow({
          id: 1, 
          empresa: data.agendador.company, 
          data_criacao: data.dataCriacao, 
          agendador: data.agendador.nome, 
          colaborador: data.colaborador.nome,
          cpf: data.colaborador.cpf, 
          ctps: data.colaborador.ctps, 
          funcao: data.colaborador.funcao, 
          data_agendado: data.data, 
          data_atendimento_medico: data.dataAtendimento, 
          data_inicio_atendimento: data.dataInicio, 
          data_inicio_exames: data.dataInicioExames, 
          tipo_exame: data.tipoExame, 
          exames: data.exames[0].nome, 
          status_atendimento: data.status, 
          status_exames: data.statusExames

        })

        resolveExcel()

      })      

      promises.push(promise)

    })

    Promise.all(promises)

      .then(() => {          
        salvaExcel()

        .then((url) => {

          console.log('Salvar URL' + url) 

          resolve(url)

        })

        .catch((error => {
          reject(error)

        }))


    })


  })       

}


exports.relatorios = functions.database.ref('/relatorios/{state}/{year}/{month}/{relatoriosId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {      
      return relatorios(change, context)
});
```

On Functions console, the log show me that the excel file was created successfully. But when uploading, a very strange error pops:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? I apreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're not showing your entire code here, it's not possible to say.  The function declaration is missing.  Also, any time I see `return new Promise` in JavaScript with more promises inside that, that raises flags that promises are not being dealt with properly. It doesn't look like you're doing anything here that requires a `new Promise`.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've update with the entire code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you are getting comes from trying to get the signed URL of a non-existant file.

When you call `bucket.upload(filename, metadata)`, you are uploading the file `/tmp/Relatorio.xlsx`, which creates a file in your bucket called `Relatorio.xlsx`. On the next line you call `bucket.file(filename);` which incorrectly associates itself with `/tmp/Relatorio.xlsx` instead of `Relatorio.xlsx`.

To fix this, you should use the `File` object that is resolved from `bucket.upload()` instead of creating it yourself:

```
bucket.upload(filename, metadata)
    .then((file) => file.getSignedURL())
    .then((url) => {
        console.log('Salvar URL' + url)
    })
```

#### Other notes and fixes

Your code also contains a lot of unnecessary `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... })` calls. This is called the *Promise constructor anti-pattern* and most of them can be removed by properly chaining the Promises. This [blog post](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) is a good crash course on Promises and how to use them properly.

Regarding your function's source code, as the `index.js` file for functions will contain multiple function definitions, you should not define variables at the top of your `index.js` file unless they are shared by all of your functions and they are stateless in case a function is called multiple times. This is particularly important when dealing with I/O or memory-intensive resources such as files.

With your current code, if the relatorios function was called twice in a short period, the saved file would contain both the old data from the first call and the new data from the current call leading to both an invalid file and a potential memory leak.

Removing the excessive promise calls and making it so that your `exceljs` code can be rerun without corrupting any data results in the following `index.js` file:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// 'exceljs' is required on-demand in MyExcelSheetHelper

admin.initializeApp();

/* HELPER CLASS */

/**
 * A helper class used to create reuseable functions that won't
 * conflict with each other
 */
class MyExcelSheetHelper {

  constructor() {
    const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

    this.workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    this.worksheet = this.workbook.addWorksheet('Relatório Consolidado');

    this.worksheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Empresa', key: 'empresa', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Data criação', key: 'data_criacao', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Responsável agendamento', key: 'agendador', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Colaborador', key: 'colaborador', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Endereço', key: 'endereco', width: 25 },
      { header: 'CPF', key: 'cpf', width: 25 },
      { header: 'CTPS', key: 'ctps', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Função', key: 'funcao', width: 25 },

      { header: 'Data agendado', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Data atendimento médico', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Data inicio atendimento', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Data inicio exames', key: 'nome_subtipo_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Tipo de exame', key: 'valor_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Exames realizados', key: 'valor_produto', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Status atendimento', key: 'tipoPagamento', width: 25 },
      { header: 'Status exames', key: 'centroCustoStr', width: 25 }
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Streams this workbook to Cloud Storage
   * @param storageFilepath - the relative path where the file is uploaded to Cloud Storage
   * @returns the signed URL for the file
   */
  salva(storageFilepath) {
    if (!storageFilepath) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('storageFilepath is required'));
    }

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

    const storageFile = bucket.file(storageFilepath);

    const uploadFilePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const stream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
          contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        });

        stream.on('finish', () => {
          resolve();
        });

        stream.on('error', error => {
          reject(error);
        });

        this.workbook.xlsx.write(stream)
          .then(() => {
            stream.end();
          });

      } catch (e) { // catches errors from createWriteStream
        reject(e);
      }
    })

    return uploadFilePromise
      .then(() => {
        var CONFIG = {                                                                      
          action: 'read',                                                               
          expires: '03-01-2500',                                                        
        };    

        bucket.file(storageFilepath).getSignedUrl(CONFIG)
        .then((signedUrl) => {

          return signedUrl
        })
      })

  }
}

/* FUNCTIONS CODE */

function criaRelatorioAgendamentos(path, querySnapshot) {
  const excelFileHelper = new MyExcelSheetHelper();
  const worksheet = excelFile.worksheet;

  // this forEach loop is synchronous, so no Promises are needed here
  querySnapshot.forEach(entrySnapshot => {
    const data = entrySnapshot.val();

    worksheet.addRow({
      id: 1,
      empresa: data.agendador.company,
      data_criacao: data.dataCriacao,
      agendador: data.agendador.nome,
      colaborador: data.colaborador.nome,
      cpf: data.colaborador.cpf,
      ctps: data.colaborador.ctps,
      funcao: data.colaborador.funcao,
      data_agendado: data.data,
      data_atendimento_medico: data.dataAtendimento,
      data_inicio_atendimento: data.dataInicio,
      data_inicio_exames: data.dataInicioExames,
      tipo_exame: data.tipoExame,
      exames: data.exames[0].nome,
      status_atendimento: data.status,
      status_exames: data.statusExames
    });
  });

  return excelFileHelper.salva(path + '/Relatorio.xlsx');
}

exports.relatorios = functions.database.ref('/relatorios/{state}/{year}/{month}/{relatoriosId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

    // Verificar relatorio agendamentos

    const snapshot = change.after;
    const data = snapshot.val();
    const dataInicial = data.dataInicial;
    const year = moment(dataInicial).format('YYYY');
    const month = moment(dataInicial).format('MM');
    const state = 'DF';
    const path = "/agendamentos/" + state + "/" +  year + "/" + month;

    return admin.database().ref(path).once('value')
      .then(valores => {
        return criaRelatorioAgendamentos(path, valores);
      });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, helped me a lot!

I changed **class MyExcelSheetHelper() {** to **class MyExcelSheetHelper {** in order to deploy the functions. 

Also,  I've changed **this.worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet** to **this.worksheet = this.workbook.addWorksheet**

Now, the file is created on storage, but the function return an error.. 

**ReferenceError: storageFile is not defined**

I already changed the variable storageFile trying to put on 'scope', but with no success..

Comment: Ok, I figure out.. changing to ** return bucket.file(storageFilepath).getSignedUrl(CONFIG) ** worked like a charm...

Also, I had to enable **Identity and Access Management (IAM) API** and set the ** Service Account Token Creator ** role to get this working..

@samthecodingman THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!!

Comment: Please note it is file.getSignedUrl() and not file.getSignedURL()

Answer (score 0):

This is the version I use to save an excel file generated with exceljs
and their respective library versions

```
// @google-cloud/storage   --> 5.3.0
// exceljs  --> 4.3.0
// moment  --> 2.29.1     
const moment = require('moment');
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');

class Excel {

constructor(nameSheet) {
    this.workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    this.workbook.creator = 'User...';
    this.workSheet = this.workbook.addWorksheet(nameSheet);
}

// ..... other code....

saveFile = async (path, filename) =>
{
    
    const storage = new Storage();
    const bucket = storage.bucket('name_bucket...');
    const storageFile = bucket.file(`${path}/${filename}`);
    const blobStream = storageFile.createWriteStream({
        contentType: 'application/ms-excel',
    });
    
    await this.workbook.xlsx.write(blobStream);
    
    blobStream.end();
    
    const config = {
        action: 'read',
        expires: moment().add(30, 'minutes').format(),
    };
    
    return await storageFile.getSignedUrl(config)
}

}
```